# Build system for eclipse plugins & RCP

Tags: eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho, build-system

I wonder if there is build system with following capabilities:

1. Install & update dependencies (plugins) in target platform on developer machine.
2. Retrieve & pack binary dependencies into OSGi bundle (from maven repos, maybe).

i.e. this build system should satisfy following use case:

1. Developer checks out plugin sources from scm.
2. Build system checks if plugin dependencies present in target platform, if no — installs them.
3. Build system checks for binary dependencies, fetches them and packs into OSGi bundle project in workspace.

I know about [Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/), but don't know if it can provision dependencies as separate process, not during build.

Also I know about [B3](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/b3/) project which has required features, but i've failed to build its plugins for Eclipse 3.7 (it depends on old Xtext & google-collections).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, now I know about target platforms in Eclipse, so I'll use them for fetching plugin dependencies.

For binary dependencies I can use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using buckminster, works with 3.5, 3.6, 3.7